# Recommendations for JSON API to use for authentication

Tags: javascript, api, framework, json, authentication

I am currently discovering the javascript framework Vue.js. I want to be able to make a login with API data, but i cant seem to find any API that has data like usernames and passwords. I have been searching for hours but i cant seem to find a single good API, i hope someone on here can recommend me a good API, i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple one to read user/pass/email info from a mysql db when I taught a course on LAMP development...

If you don't want to deal with account verification, etc. then I'd recommend using one or more of the "sign in with ..." services from google, facebook, etc.